# Change of variables in multiple integral using standard formula

Tags: integration

**Question:**

Express the integral $I=\iint\limits_R\,(x-y)\,dx\,dy$ in terms of u and v

where $x=u(1+v)$ and $y=u-v$

**My answer:**

Using:

$\iint\limits_R\,F(x,y)\,dx\,dy=\iint\limits_RF(\,f(u,v),g(u,v)\,)\,J(u,v)
\,du\,dv$

where

$x=f(u,v)$ , $y=g(u,v)$ and $J(u,v)=\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{u}} & \frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{u}} \\ 
\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{v}} & \frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{v}} \\
\end{vmatrix}$

I get:

$J(u,v)=\begin{vmatrix}
1+v & 1 \\ 
u & -1 \\
\end{vmatrix}$

and so

$I=\iint\limits_R\,(u+uv-u+v)(-1-v-u)\,du\,dv\therefore$

$I=-\iint\limits_R\,v(1+u)(1+v+u)$

But the source text from which I am working gives the answer as

$I=\iint\limits_R\,v(1+u)(1+v+u)$

(The negative of my result).

Am I wrong or the original source?

Comment: Your region transforms too...

Answer (score 1):

In your statement of the change of variables, you've forgotten an important thing: it's not just the Jacobian that shows up, it's the *absolute value* of the Jacobian. $$\iint_RF(x,y)\,dx\,dy = \iint_SF(f(u,v), g(u,v))|J(u,v)|\,du\,dv.$$ That explains the difference in sign.

Also, I should point out that the region of integration should be different in the $xy$-integral than in the $uv$-integral.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the absolute value requirement.